# Equivalent for tail -f output\worker*.log in Powershell

Tags: powershell, tail

I need to output several logfiles - while they are written - to the shell.

In the unix version of my script this is achieved by `tail -f output\worker*.log`. **Note the wildcard.**

In Powershell I tried `Get-Content -Path "output\worker*.log" -Wait`, but this only prints the first logfile it can find to the shell.

For completion, here is my code where i call my program:

```
foreach ($worker in $workers)
{
  Write-Host "  Start $worker in background"

  $block = {& $args[0] $args[1] $args[2] $args[3] $args[4] $args[5] $args[6] 2> $args[7] > $args[8]}
  start-job -name $worker -scriptblock $block -argumentlist `
    "$strPath\worker\bin\win32\php.exe", `
    "-q", `
    "-c", `
    "$strPath\worker\conf\php_win32.ini", `
    "$strPath\worker\bin\os-independant\logfilefilter\logfilefilter.php", `
    "-f", `
    "$strPath\worker\$worker\conf\logfilefilter-$worker.xml", `
    "$strPath\output\$worker-error.log", `
    "$strPath\output\$worker.log"
}

Get-Content -Path "output\worker*.log" -Wait
```

In my test case there are 8 workers and logfiles( `output\worker01.log`, `output\worker02.log`, `output\worker03.log`, `output\worker04.log`, `output\worker05.log`, `output\worker06.log`, `output\worker07.log`, `output\worker08.log` )

Is there a workaround to output all these logfiles? Or is it possible to duplicate the stdout stream from the background process to print it in the shell?

Answer (score 0):

You can duplicate the the output streams by reading them directly from the output buffers of the child jobs.

Here's a demo script.  Note that for the Verbose output, I'm removing output from the buffer as it's read, so that it doesn't get re-displayed on subsequent reads.  This doesn't appear to have any affect on the Receive Job buffers for the job.  If you do a Receive Job on it after the script completes, you'll still get the Verbose output all over again.

```
$sb = {
$VerbosePreference = 'Continue'
for ($i = 1; $i -le 100; $i++ )
{
  start-sleep -Milliseconds 150
  Write-Verbose "$(get-date)"
  write-progress -activity "Search in Progress" -status "$i% Complete:" -percentcomplete $i;}
}

$job = start-job -ScriptBlock $sb 
$verbose = ($job.ChildJobs[0].Verbose)

While ($job.State -ne 'Completed')
{
  $job.ChildJobs |
   foreach {
   Start-Sleep -seconds 1
   $Pct_Complete = $_.Progress | select -last 1 | select -ExpandProperty PercentComplete
   Write-Host "`rBackground job $($_.ID) is $Pct_Complete percent completed." -ForegroundColor Cyan 
     While ($verbose.count){
      Write-Host $verbose[0] -ForegroundColor Gray
      $verbose.removeat(0)}
      }

}
write-host "`nDone!"
```